# Share DBAdapter Between Activities

Tags: android

Ok so in my application I have a DBAdapter class, that does its job well. In the main Activity, I have a variable `this.dbAdapter`. I would like to share this variable with other Activites, so I don't have to create a new DBAdapter in each Activity.

How would be the best way of doing this? Should I do something like `intent.putExtra("DbAdapter", this.dbAdapter);`? Or is there another way that I should go about it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't answer your question but I can tell you intent extras only support a few different types, and I don't believe DBAdapter is one of them. Plus you'd only end up passing a static to it rather than a reference.

Comment: If you call open() in onResume and close() in onPause, you should not worry about creating a new DbAdapter object in each Activity. Also, I'm no expert, but I imagine that you would run into issues with Contexts using your method.

Comment: That is this DBAdapter of yours? Is it subclass of CursorAdapter? Is it just yours custom class to simplify work with DB? Without that type of information it's pretty hard to answer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that integrates best with Android is to [create a Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) and have each activity query it, using an Adapter to tie your query results to your widgets. However, you can get by with just creating a new DBAdapter in each Activity, making sure to close all resources when the Activity is paused. If you need to persist state in your Adapter, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: By the responses on this page, I'll just go with creating a new DBAdapter on each Activity.

Comment: This is definitely not "the best solution"... you don't have to create a `ContentProvider` just to simply share the adapter across multiple activities...

Comment: After 3+ years of Android development, I've found that it's the best solution for me. It ties in the closest with the Android OS, which gives you a lot of awesome things for free. To make it easier to use, I've abstracted it out so it's actually easier than writing DB stuff, as you don't need to write any SQL: https://github.com/mitmel/SimpleContentProvider (it's sorta like an ORM, but doesn't create tons of objects).

Comment: @AlexLockwood I should suppose I should amend, "best solution" is always relative. Perhaps the above should read, "solution that integrates the best with Android". When you create a `ContentProvider`, you then create content URIs. When you create content URIs, you can resolve activites based data-driven intents. When you use data-driven intents, then you have an amazing amount of flexibility in how your app flows. For many quick DB use cases, multiple instances of `DBAdapter`s are actually the best solution.

Comment: Yeah, I mean I agree that `ContentProvider`s can be great, but just as often they aren't really necessary. I just wanted to point out that there are many options and implementing a `ContentProvider` is definitely not the 100% clear cut way to achieve something so simple... that's kind of how I interpreted your assertion that it is the "best solution". That is, it could be the "best solution" in the long run (i.e. if you decide to implement a search interface later on), but it's not necessarily the best solution in the short run at all. Hopefully my comment makes a little more sense now. :)

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to share this variable with other Activites, so I don't have to create a new DBAdapter in each > Activity.

Please don't do this. Adapters are tightly coupled with their activities and underlying data. All you will do is cause your app to crash.

Comment: Are you sure it's some kind of CursorAdapter subclass? Or I just didn't understood something?

Comment: @Chiggins: Just create the new `DBAdapter`.